# Filtering custom post types by two custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to filter a custom post type (Artwork) to only pull through posts of that type with the 'Featured' custom field checkbox and the 'Digital Art' value of a drop-down list custom field.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
'post_type' => 'artwork',
'offset' => 1,
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'artwork_genre',
        'value'     => 'digitalart',
        'compare'   => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'featured',
        'value'     => 'feature',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    ),
),
);
```

This isn't working.

Comment: Try changing compare => IN to compare => '=' .

Comment: @OrlandoP. Still not pulling through any results, thank you for the suggestion though!